# Can't Edit the file outside of my program after opening that file inside program. CGM file won't get released

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, connection

I have a problem with the releasing the CGM file after it opens. If I open a CGM file in my program and then open another file or many others, the program won't release the first file. I have to close the program and restart again so that the files will be released. Here is my code. How can I release the file when I open another file without restarting the program.

```
    private void btnCGM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;
        openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.Filter = "CGM Files (*.cgm)|*.cgm";
        openFile.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFile.Multiselect = false;
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(openFile.FileName.ToString());                
            lblSchematic.Text = FileName;
            cgmPath = openFile.FileName.Replace(FileName, "");
            loadCGM(FileName);
        }
    }

     private void loadCGM(string filename)
    {
        sdi.filename(filename);
        sdi.SourceFile = cgmPath + filename;
        this.Text = getFileName(filename);
        sdi.Refresh();
        this.Refresh();
        sdiToolBarPosition();
        lblRecNo.Text = getRecNo(filename).ToString();
        TheRealFileRec = Int32.Parse(lblRecNo.Text);
    }

    public static void DataConnection()
    {
        if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Password pw = new Password();
                pw.PasswordPrompt += new EventHandler<PasswordEventArgs>(pw_PasswordPrompt);
                pw.ShowDialog();
                //Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
            }
        }
    }

        private string getFileName(string CGM)
    {
        string title = "";
        string SQL = @"select a.title from files a where a.filename = ?";//, CGM);
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, cn))
        {
            DataConnection();                
            OleDbParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", OleDbType.VarChar, 40);
            param.Value = CGM;
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dr.Read();
                title = dr["title"].ToString();
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        return title;
    }

    private double getRecNo(string filename)
    {
        double recNo = 0;
        string SQL = @"select a.recno from files a where a.filename = ?";
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, cn))
        {
            DataConnection();
            OleDbParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", OleDbType.VarChar, 40);
            param.Value = filename;
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dr.Read();
                recNo = Convert.ToDouble(dr["recno"]);
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        return recNo;

    private void GetXmlConnection()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myDocuments))
        {
            using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
            {
                XmlDocument pathDoc = new XmlDocument();
                pathDoc.Load(xr);                    
                XmlNode node = pathDoc.SelectSingleNode("Path");
                databasePath = node.InnerText.Trim();
                cn = new OleDbConnection(databasePath);
                lblDatabase.Text = Path.GetFileName(databasePath);
                cn.close();
            }
        }
         populateComboBox();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you opening the file?  Is that in `loadCGM()`?  Are you closing the FileStream when you're done?

Comment: There is no file opening here. You are only selecting a file using OpenFileDialog. So it should be inside the method loadCGM. Show that code.

Comment: @Steve I added the loadCGM()

Comment: Still missing any kind of stream creation and reading. Too many points where you could have the error. `sdi.filename(filename), getFileName(filename) getRecNo(filename)`

Comment: @Steve getFileName and getRecNo methods are added too

Comment: @user603948 You aren't closing your `XmlTextReader`.

Comment: @intracept the using disposes of the reader and should release the file

Comment: @ConradFrix Yes, I know it should, but it never hurts to explicitly call `Close()`. :)

Comment: I have a suspicion. When you talk about locked files, you're referring to the CGM files or to the database file? It seems that you're using global variables for your connections. It is difficult to understand if the connection is properly closed. Points out that the current practice is to create the connection, use it and  close/dispose it at the same point where it is needed precisely to avoid inadvertently leaving the connection open.

Comment: @Steve I'm talking about CGM files. when I open the cgm file with program and then open another file and edit, my program doesn't release the first cgm that I opened before.